# Need image glow on hover using Lightbox

Tags: html, css, hover, lightbox, glow

I have been looking for the past couple of days and have not been able to find anything helpful. I am trying to get the same glow effect that is used on the Lightbox demo page ( http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ ). I want to make it so that when I hover over my thumbnails, the same kind of animated glow happens. But I cant find anything that really helps. Does anyone know how they achieved this?

Comment: Are you talking about the blue outline on the images?

Comment: That seems to be a simply transition of the background-color of the link element around the image from white to a blue – it shows within the padding area of the link and is restricted to rounded corners at the edges by a border-radius. (Which makes it look quite cheap IMHO. I’d think other ways of achieving something similar, like a blurred box-shadow, could achieve this effect quite better looking.)

Comment: The thing is, when I did try to add a box shadow, for some reason it would never be around the actual image, but it would appear starting in one corder of the image, and be totally different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what they did:

```
.example-image-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out
}

.example-image-link:hover {
    background-color: #4ae;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0;
    -o-transition: background-color 0;
    transition: background-color 0
}

.example-image {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px
}
```

The important bits being the background-color and the transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/DjXn9/